# Must you have an uncompleted destination card in Ticket to Ride?

Tags: ticket-to-ride

Put another way, once you complete the destinations on your initial destination cards, do you have to draw a new destination card or can you play without having an uncompleted destination?

Answer (score 2):

Drawing Destination cards later in the game is optional - the only time you have to draw Destination cards is at the start of the game.

If you finish all of yours early enough then it may be worth drawing more, but if you finish them later in the game it would be unproductive to draw more, and your efforts are better spent trying to block other players.

Since Destination cards are always kept secret from other players until scoring, any rule that did say you had to have incomplete Destination cards would be based entirely on trust.

Comment: It's not always unproductive to draw more destination cards late in the game.  Sometimes you can get lucky and draw one (or more) that you already have covered by your existing trains on the board; netting you extra points "for free".  It's a gamble though.